# How to change filemtime files directory delete?

Tags: php, filetime

I have the following codes.

```
$days = 7;   

// Check if the file is older than X days old  
if (filemtime($path.$file) < ( time() - ( $days * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) )  
{  
    // Do the deletion  
    unlink($path.$file);  
}
```

I want to change `$days` to `$minute`, how do I go about changing it?

Comment: Do you want to check if the file is older than `x` minutes instead?

Comment: Would this be too simple to answer? Just a Math question.

Comment: yes do not delete at day delete files at minute new variable $minute = 1;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check if the file is older than `x` minutes, the following codes might apply.

```
$minutes = 15;

// Check if the file is older than x minutes
if (filemtime($path.$file) < ( time() - ( $minutes * 60 ) ) ) {  
    // Do the deletion  
    unlink($path.$file);  
}
```

Comment: do not remember variable filetime  * 24 * 60 * 60 ) ) )   ok delete H.m  * 60 ) ) )  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$minute = 1440 * $days;
// there are 1440 minutes in a day
```

I have no idea if this is what you were asking.. but it seems appropriate.

Comment: no $days = 7;  change variable minute ? $minute = 1;   

// Check if the file is older than X days old  
if (filemtime($path.$file) < ( time() - ( $minute * 60 * 60 ) ) )  
{    ???\

Comment: Can you please justify your answer and ask the questions as comments? =)